# Gatsby Dynamic styling not working in production build

Tags: gatsby, tailwind-css

I am new in Gatsby and I am using tailwind css with postcss. Some of the color configurations I defined in theme object of tailwind.config.js is working in dev environment but not in production. I have tried cleaning cache and deleting public folder and re-building it. That did not solve the problem. My theme object in tailwind.config.js is like this:

```
theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      primary: {
        DEFAULT: '#4F9C3A',
        900: '#25441c',
      },
      secondary: {
        0: '#ff9563',
        DEFAULT: '#E66437',
        9: '#ae3409',
      },
      footer: {
        light: '#e66437',
        DEFAULT: '#383e42',
        dark: '#26292c',
      },
      neutral: {
        0: '#ffffff',
        DEFAULT: '#ffffff',
        1: '#fafafa',
        9: '#000000',
      },
      accent: {
        1: '#388ac5',
        DEFAULT: '#293842',
      },
      brown: {
        DEFAULT: '#C9AC75',
        2: '#44261c',
      },
      black: '#000000',
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I have been able to pinpoint source of the problem. I am fetching which class names to apply from a json file using gatsby-transformer-json. I have something like the following code segment to set background color which is working in development environment but not in production.

```
<div className={`bg-${color}>
The development build shows proper background color for this segment but production build does not. 
</div>
```

Comment: probably it's not a problem with color settings but with a purge. Maybe you didn't configure it or something. Need to see your whole tailwind.config.js and where your working files are (I'm not familiar with Gatsby)

Comment: Have you tried moving those styles to global styles?

Comment: There's a typo in your last snippet, should be: ``<div className={`bg-${color}`}>``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR:**
Don't use string concatenation in your class names when you use the `purge` option in tailwind.config.js. Instead, provide **full class names**.

Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production

**UPDATE March 1st, 2021**

Thanks @robotu for bringing another great option to the table: you can add a `safelist` option to your `tailwind.config.js` file, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  purge: {
    content: ['./src/**/*.html'],
    safelist: ['bg-primary', 'bg-secondary']
  }
}
```

---

**Original OP Code/Intent**

You've done this: `` <div className={`bg-${color}`> ``

But TailwindCSS prefers something like this: `<div className={ color === "red" ? "bg-red" : "bg-blue" }>`

My guess is that you could probably use a function/hook that returns the full class name in the case that you have many possible colors, but I haven't tested that yet.

---

#### The longer version:

You aren't showing us your full tailwind.config.js file, but I'll assume you're using the `purge` option somewhere in there.

Continuing with Ferran's answer: I'd say the real issue is how PurgeCSS, which Tailwind uses under the hood during the build process when you include the `purge` option in your config, determines what classes to purge during the build process.

It finds any strings that match the regular expression:

```
/[^<>"'`\s]*[^<>"'`\s:]/g
```

Which will naively find almost everything, only stopping at specific syntax symbols. It will then try to preserve every match, and purge the rest. So it will find `bg-` and `color`, preserve them, but will purge `bg-color` as that was not found by PurgeCSS's regex.

From TailwindCSS docs:

> That means that it is important to avoid dynamically creating class strings in your templates with string concatenation, otherwise PurgeCSS won't **know to preserve those classes**.

Comment: An alternative can be to add a "safelist" option in the tailwind.config.js file: `purge: {content: ['./src/**/*.html', ..........], safelist: ['bg-primary', 'bg-secondary', .... .....]},},`. In the code you can continue to use `bg-${color}`

Comment: Thanks @robotu! I've added this to the official answer. This is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Tailwind + Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/tailwind-css/), there are two important statements to consider:

> In `gatsby-browser.js` add an import rule for your Tailwind directives
> and custom CSS so that they are accounted for in build.

And:

> **Note**: By default, PurgeCSS only runs on the build command as it is a
> relatively slow process. The development server will include all
> Tailwind classes, so it’s highly recommended you test on a build
> server before deploying.

In your case, the issue may come from the PurgeCSS directive because it's not present so it may be purging all the styling. Fix it by:

```
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
   purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
  }
```

*Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/gatsby*

Or:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.js", "./src/**/*.jsx", "./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"],
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

*Source: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/tailwind-css/*

One other thing you can try is to move your styles to global styles in your `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
import "tailwindcss/dist/base.min.css"
```

I'm assuming that in your `gatsby-config.js` you have already declared the proper instances:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    options: {
      postCssPlugins: [
        require("tailwindcss"),
        require("./tailwind.config.js"), // Optional: Load custom Tailwind CSS configuration
      ],
    },
  },
],
```

***Note**: Optionally you can add a corresponding configuration file (by default it will be `tailwind.config.js`). If you are adding a custom configuration, you will need to load it after `tailwindcss`.*